# Scroll effect with transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll

can anybody help me in this issue, I want to implement scroll effect like in this site: https://neematic.com/.
I just want to understand the direction in which to move. As I understand, we put on the body `"overflow: hidden"`, after that the event on the scroll stops working for us, we put absolute positioning for all  tags, and put the event on onmousewheel, and when we scroll, we change the location of our sections with "`transform: translateY ()`". Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

you have all the reason that only you are attacked that all the sections have instead of `position:absolute` that `position:fixed` sea and are independent nodes and thus easier to manipulate